# Windows Updates gives an error while checking for updates

Tags: command-line, windows-update

I have created a junction from c:\windows\softwaredistribution to d:\updates.

```
mklink /j c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution d:\updates1
```

Unfortunately, when I start checking for updates I get a 80070005 error. The Windows Update log file says:

```
2022-07-21 17:30:00.7818808 8760  7836  ComApi          * START *   Federated Search ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator (cV: kgWcI37TOEW2CyA8.0.1.0)
2022-07-21 17:30:00.7870404 9764  3908  IdleTimer       WU operation (SR.MoUpdateOrchestrator ID 33) started; operation # 163; does use network; is not at background priority
2022-07-21 17:30:00.7870449 9764  3908  IdleTimer       Activate PDC state for Network
2022-07-21 17:30:00.7873267 9764  3908  IdleTimer       Incremented PDC RefCount for Network to 1
2022-07-21 17:30:00.7874305 9764  10940 Agent           Processing auto/pending service registrations and recovery.
2022-07-21 17:30:00.8110154 9764  10940 SLS             Get response for service 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 - forceExpire[False] asyncRefreshOnExpiry[False]
2022-07-21 17:30:00.8110262 9764  10940 SLS             path used for cache lookup: /SLS/{9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}/x64/10.0.19044.1620/0?CH=438&L=nl-NL;en-US&P=&PT=0x65&WUA=10.0.19041.1503&MK=Microsoft+Corporation&MD=Surface+Go+2
2022-07-21 17:30:00.8111412 9764  10940 SLS             Retrieving SLS response from server...
2022-07-21 17:30:00.8128655 9764  10940 SLS             Making request with URL HTTPS://slscr.update.microsoft.com/SLS/{9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}/x64/10.0.19044.1620/0?CH=438&L=nl-NL;en-US&P=&PT=0x65&WUA=10.0.19041.1503&MK=Microsoft+Corporation&MD=Surface+Go+2 and send SLS events.
2022-07-21 17:30:00.9490317 9764  10940 Misc            *FAILED* [80070005] Library download error. Will retry. Retry Counter:0
2022-07-21 17:30:01.0831975 9764  10940 Misc            *FAILED* [80070005] Library download error. Will retry. Retry Counter:1
2022-07-21 17:30:01.2038211 9764  10940 Misc            *FAILED* [80070005] Library download error. Will retry. Retry Counter:2
2022-07-21 17:30:01.3225189 9764  10940 SLS             Complete the request URL HTTPS://slscr.update.microsoft.com/SLS/{9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}/x64/10.0.19044.1620/0?CH=438&L=nl-NL;en-US&P=&PT=0x65&WUA=10.0.19041.1503&MK=Microsoft+Corporation&MD=Surface+Go+2 with [80070005] and http status code[200] and send SLS events.
2022-07-21 17:30:01.3225260 9764  10940 SLS             *FAILED* [80070005] GetDownloadedOnWeakSSLCert
2022-07-21 17:30:01.3237371 9764  10940 SLS             *FAILED* [80070005] Method failed [CSLSClient::GetResponse:625]
2022-07-21 17:30:01.3237475 9764  10940 Misc            *FAILED* [80070005] Method failed [CSLSEndpointProvider::GetWUClientData:2275]
2022-07-21 17:30:01.3237511 9764  10940 Misc            *FAILED* [80070005] EP: get client data
2022-07-21 17:30:01.3237549 9764  10940 Misc            *FAILED* [80070005] Method failed [CSLSEndpointProvider::GetSecondaryServicesEnabledState:1689]
2022-07-21 17:30:01.3237612 9764  10940 Agent           *FAILED* [80070005] Method failed [CAgentServiceManager::DetectAndToggleServiceState:2910]
2022-07-21 17:30:01.3237709 9764  10940 Agent           *FAILED* [80070005] Failed to resolve federated serviceId 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
2022-07-21 17:30:01.3237826 9764  10940 Agent           *FAILED* [80070005] Failed to execute service registration call {D3F44EB5-DBF5-4C07-9C82-CA42CEE24185} (cV: kgWcI37TOEW2CyA8.0.1.0.1)
```

As soon as I remove the junction the error message is gone.

I tried one procmon to find access denied errors, but did only find one on HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WBEM\CIMOM.

Any ideas to get this solved? By the way, the source is on a MicroSD card with exFAT formatted on a Surface 2 Go.

Comment: I assume when you made the junction point, you disabled the service and renamed the original folder, before you created it?

Comment: I created the new folder, stopped the Windows Update service, deleted the old SoftwareDistribution folder, created the junction and started the Windows Update service. The new SoftwareDistribution folder is filled with content - but no updates - and while checking for updates the 80070005 error message. That is ACCESS DENIED. The MicroSD card has been exFAT formatted.

Comment: Why was in configured as exFAT instead of NTFS? I can almost guarantee you the issue is the exFAT partition

Comment: The issue is also possibly the fact that there is no way for you (or anyone) to duplicate the permissions that Windows Update expects for the SoftwareDistribution folder. I don't think that this is a good method to save on disk space.

Comment: I tried a different approach. Now, I created an empty SoftwareDistributiion folder and linked an empty NTFS partition to it, using Disk Management. The same issue. The new partition has been formatted as NTFS.